# How to resolve RecoverableDataAccessException in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat7

I am using JNDI configuration with JDBCtemplate as autowired in spring boot application.

Connection is creating successfully. But when we execute save or search operation it gets failed with below error:

```
org.springframwwork.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: CallableStatementCallback; SQL [] Closed Connection ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
```

I have tried below stackoverflow solution as well but it doesn't worked.

[What is the cause of "RecoverableDataAccessException" received when checking health of database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058614/what-is-the-cause-of-recoverabledataaccessexception-received-when-checking-hea)

Please find the below context.xml configuration used for the connection:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/xyz" 
auth="Container" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
url=""
username="" 
password=""
minActive="30" 
maxActive="100" 
minIdle="10" 
maxIdle="10" 
initialSize="10"
jmxEnabled="true" 
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000" 
maxWait="10000" 
logAbandoned="true"
testOnBorrow="true" 
testOnConnect="false" 
suspectTimeout="120"
validationQuery="select 1 from dual" 
validationInterval="30000"
initSQL="select 1 from dual" 
removeAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
maxAge="180000"
accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true">
</Resource>
```

Tried changing the maxWait to -1 in context.xml as well.

JdbcTemplate is getting autowired successfully. Mostly search operations are working fine but when we do save operation its getting failed with SQLRecoverableException as mentioned above.

I am creating SimpleJdbcCall object using jdbcTemplate object and then executing it as to save the details in oracle database.

```
SimpleJdbcCall save = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("xxpqr_abc")
.withCatalogName("xxpqr__xx_abc").withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("abc", OracleTypes.ARRAY, "abc1"),
new SqlParameter("xyz", OracleTypes.ARRAY, "xyz1"),
new SqlOutParameter("error_msg", Types.VARCHAR));

Map<String, Object> saveResult = save.execute(
new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("pqr", new SqlArrayValue(empDetailsArray))
.addValue("pqr", saveObj.getSubmitFlag()));
```

During execute got the java.lang.NullPointerException.

Same operation is working fine if connection created using spring @configuration annotation using separate class. But that doesn't provide connection pooling.

Comment: Issue is resolved when did the entire setup as fresh, it might with issue with the server which is closing the db connection.